# multi-word abbrev expansion

Tags: emacs

I found this mailing list [message](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2007-10/msg02152.html) about multi-word abbreviations, but
still can't get expansion to work.

I have these two abbreviations defined:

```
"agw"          0    "a great whale"
"a g w"         0    "a great whale"
```

pressing space after "agw" works, but not "a g w".  However if I call
`(abbrev-expansion "a g w")`, then the correct expansion is returned.

The question is how to get Emacs to search beyond one word boundary backwards?

Yes, yasnippet exists and I use it, but abbrev is more seamless (e.g. press
space after "1/2" turns it into unicode half).  I also don't want to change
the syntax table.

Answer (score 0):

SPACE, before inserting itself, will look for an abbrev before point to expand. It uses `backward-word', which will stop at the previous space. Thus SPACE can't expand spaces inside abbrevs.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Andreas, it does not work because by default abbrevs only work if they are made up of chars that are "word constituent" and " " is not a word constituent. You can change this rule, tho, for a given table, with something like `(abbrev-table-put <table> :regexp <regexp>)` where a regexp like `"\\<\\(\\w+:?\\)\\W*"` would pretty much reproduce the default behavior.

Now for your case, you want a regexp that will match "a g w" and "agw" but note that it shouldn't match the "agw" of "dawg" and neither should it match "a g agw", which makes it a bit tricky.  One way to do that is to define your regexp as `(concat "\\<" (regexp-opt '("agw" "a g w")) "\\W*")`, which is fairly simple to do but has the downside that it requires changing the regexp any time you add an abbrev.