# abbreviation not working in emacs

Tags: emacs

when I add an abbreviation
`("s:", "std::")`

It doesn't work while other abbreviation above and below work.

Is there something wrong in the syntax ? How can I get this to work ?

Comment: How do you create it? `.emacs`, `C-X ag`?

Comment: I write it in abbrev_defs.el and reload it.

Answer (score 2):

As ring0 explains, it does not work because by default abbrevs only work if they are made up of chars that are "word constituent" and ":" is not a word constituent.
You can change this rule, tho, for a given table, with something like `(abbrev-table-put <table> :regexp "\\<\\(\\w+:?\\)\\W*")` where a regexp like `"\\<\\(\\w+:?\\)\\W*"` would pretty much reproduce the default behavior.

Comment: Is there a multi-word abbrev solution for my Q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426748/multi-word-abbrev-expansion ?

Answer (score 0):

The character `:`, along with space, `?` ... are not considered to be part of a *word* (as per Emacs definition) and trigger the *abbrev* mechanism that detects if the word typed prior to that `:` is an abbreviation and has to be expanded ([Using Word Abbrev](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch32_11.htm)).

Thus, while the `s:` abbrev is defined, entering the `:` of

```
s:
```

makes Emacs trigger the search of `s` as an abbreviation. In order words, abbreviations that contain punctuation marks cannot be expanded.

The simpler solution would be to choose digits + letters, for instance

```
8s or s8
```

--

There is a *regexp* that identifies what are the characters that trigger the abbrev search, but it works for [dynamic abbrevs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dabbrev-Customization.html#Dabbrev-Customization) only.

I tried to modify the behavior of *backward-word* but it is not even used to capture the backward word (abbrev) in recent versions of Emacs.